# How to set up margins in Mathematica to write a paper

Tags: front-end, text

I'm trying to do a problem write-up for my quantum mechanics class and would like use *Mathematica*, since I'm going to be using matrix mechanics, and it seems like the best way to write a lot of matrices, in line, very quickly. However, I'm worried that the default margins are too large to print out a paper. How do you change the default sizes of the margins?
Bonus points to answering the following:

> Are there any sites that give a comprehensive guide to text editing in *Mathematica*?

Is there any other software that might be better suited for mathematical writing? My professor is crazy about $\LaTeX$, but I don't really know where to start with that.

I'm on Windows 10

Comment: With respect to $\LaTeX$, see [this Academia.SE question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56511).

Comment: The one and only thing that I keep recommending in cases like this is: [install LyX](http://www.lyx.org/), it will let you do anything you need. LyX uses LaTeX behind the scenes, but you can use it without knowing anything about that. For margins, just go to `Document > Settings > Page Margins` and customize it any way you want. Or, use a predefined document class such as `Koma-Script Article` which already comes with adjusted margins. The default $\LaTeX$ margins are huge because the creators thought it's more aesthetic and well-balanced. But in the business (MS) world, nobody cared.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to set margins.

1. Select Printing Options... from the Printing Settings sub-menu of the File menu.
2. OS X (my system) a drop-down sheet will appear with edit field for the page margins. On Windows I would expect a very similar dialog to appear.

[image: print-menu]

[image: margin-setup]